# Create a script that dies when it detects base64 in the $_Post array

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have been trying to create a little script that dies when it detects base64 encoded information being posted to our server.

For some reason it is not entering the loop ...

```
if (in_array('base64_decode', $_POST, true)) { ... }
```

When I test it. What am I missing?

**Edit:** Sorry for this misunderstanding I wasn't clear enough. I am having things like ...

```
[gkwdwjfvzjpj] => eval(base64_decode($_POST....
```

Posted to the server and I want to know how can I just detect this string.

Comment: Rather then checking for what you **don't** want, use validation to check to ensure the data submitted is valid.

Comment: `base64_decode` isn't valid [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), but that's not your problem. What you may be detecting is `<form>` submits with an `<input value='base64_decode'>`.

Comment: Your edit did not clarify what you *want to do / prevent*. If you only want to "detect this string", you are treating the symptom, not the cause. Are you inserting POSTed contents somewhere in the page? Don't do that! Are you directly inserting POSTed contents into JavaScript or using `eval` to parse user content? (be it PHP of JavaScript) - Don't do that!

Answer (score 2):

What your code searches for is whether or not the **string** `"base64_encode"` is one of the POSTed values.

If you want to check if `base64_decode` is *in a substring* of the POSTed data:

```
function spam_in_post_values () {
  foreach ($_POST as $postval) {
    if (strpos($postval, 'base64_decode') !== false) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

However, it seems that you are inserting POSTed data into the HTML, **which is a bad idea**.

There is a principle in programming called [**Don't trust user input**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Don't_trust_user_input). You should:

- **never ever** directly insert user input into the HTML

  ```
  <p><?php echo $_POST['userdata']; ?></p>
  ```

  when the user posts something like

  ```
  "</p><script>location.href='http://otherwebsite';</script>"
  ```

  your users will be kidnapped!

  The same is true for attributes, **never** use unescaped userdata in attributes:

  ```
  <a onclick="alert('Hello <?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>!')">
  ```

  When the user posts `"'); location.href='http://spamsite.com';('"`
  users of your website will get kidnapped!
- **never ever** directly `eval` user input in PHP:

  ```
  $x = $_POST['x'];   // we expect "5"
  $y = $_POST['y'];   // we expect "3"
  $operator = $_POST['operator'];   // we expect "*", "+", "-", "/"
  $result = eval($x . $operator . $y);
  ```

  When the user sends malicious data, he can do **everything you can do with your privileges**
  in PHP. Delete files, send emails, download and install malware to your server, and so on.
- **never ever** run `eval` on user input in JavaScript (even better, never use `eval`!)
  For the same reasons outlined above, malicious input can run arbitrary code in your client.

  If you expect to get JSON data, use `JSON.parse(jsondata)` to get them as an object (or `jQuery.parseJSON(...)`, or `angular.parseJSON(...)`, or whatever your library provides).

  This also extends to "hidden" uses of `eval`, like `new Function("arg", userSuppliedString)`, event handlers `element.onclick = "alert('<user supplied value>')"`, setTimeout/setInterval calls `setTimeout("element.textContent = " + userSuppliedValue, 3000)`, etc.

---

Instead of testing for data that you do *not* want, validate that you received data you *do* want.

Comment: Sorry, this is a great answer for my question. But I probably needed to add clarification around what I was asking. Please See the updated post.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your changes. Please check out [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help understand your future questions.